# as400 date query

Tags: information-retrieval, ibm-midrange

To query the last 7 days from today in as400 as it stores the dates in char type how to retrieve the results from today as i tried using such as

```
        where chardate >= char(days(curdate()) + 7)
```

but its still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the last 7 days from today:

```
where 
date(substr(chardate,1,4) || '-' || 
substr(chardate,5,2) || '-' || 
substr(chardate,7,2)) between current date - 7 days and current date
```

To perform a character range comparison:

```
where
chardate between 
substr(char(current date - 7 days, iso),1,4) ||
substr(char(curernt date - 7 days, iso),6,2) ||
substr(char(current date - 7 days, iso),9,2)
and 
substr(char(current date, iso),1,4) ||
substr(char(current date, iso),6,2) ||
substr(char(current date, iso),9,2)
```

Comment: @JamesA: This can be a good alternative, as long as you aren't expecting your query to use any indexes that include `chardate`.

Comment: But still its returning more than 65 thousand rows rather than for 7 days rows

Comment: @jbs123: Updated example to retrieve last 7 days rows.

Comment: Well i got the error as value in date,time or timestamp string not valid is it possible to convert the existing char-date column and records into date-type i hope its the only solution for manipulation

Comment: The error indicates you have some records where the chardate is not in YYYYMMDD format or contains invalid dates.  You may have to filter those out with a CASE statement.  The other option is to perform a character to character comparison as recommended by @dmc although you are still going to have issues with the invalid dates.

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to the answer.  The first involves date math on this particular flavor of DB2.  The DB2 expression equivalent to `curdate()) + 7` is `current date + 7 days`.

The second involves converting date values to character values (or vice versa) so we can compare them.  We need to know what format `chardate` stores dates in before we can really crack that one.  Let's assume it's in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  Then you can use `char(current date + 7 days, iso)` to get seven days in the future in the same format.

So, with that assumption, your where statement would be

```
where chardate >= char(current date + 7 days, iso)
```

There are several standard date formats that `date` can convert to:

- ISO: `YYYY-MM-DD`
- USA: `MM/DD/YYYY`
- EUR: `DD.MM.YYYY`
- JIS: `YYYY-MM-DD`

If your `chardate` is in a different format, you will need to do some rather fiddly work with `substr`.  For example, to convert `YYYY-MM-DD` to `YYYYMMDD` you'd need something like

```
substr(char(current date, iso), 1, 4) ||
substr(char(current date, iso), 5, 2) ||
substr(char(current date, iso), 7, 2)
```

A major problem with this method is that formats that aren't stored in "year month day" order can't be reliably compared.  That is, `12311969` (i.e., `MMDDYYYY`) will compare as greater than `01012011`, since as far as the database is concerned, you're comparing two eight-digit numbers.  (That's why you should almost always store dates in actual `date` fields or in `YYYYMMDD` or similar properly ordered format.)

I've had great success using a free utility called [idate](http://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm), which provides SQL user-defined functions (UDFs) to convert dates stored in char & numeric fields into dates.  Note that this solution requires the availability of an RPG compiler.

Comment: where chardate >= date(current date + 7 days, iso) i got the error coloumn iso not in specified tables and my date format is in yyyymmdd char-type i tried the three query above but it didnt work. Also am getting the same error Value in date,time or timestamp string not valid

Comment: @jbs123 @dmc made a typo with the example where statement.  It should be "where chardate >= char(current date + 7 days, iso)"

Comment: But still the query is not functioning for the 7 days